# Fetch time from mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, time

I am using the code below to fetch time entity called `fajr_begins` from `mysql`. I am able to print `fajr_begins` which is in the format: 5:27:00, how can i convert this to a time format in python, so that i can manipulate the time and add 15mins?

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_remote_host, user=mysql_remote_host_user, password=mysql_remote_host_password, database=mysql_remote_host_database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from prayertimes where DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())" )
results = cursor.fetchall()
id, date, fajr_begins, fajr_jamaat, sunrise, zuhr_begins, zuhr_jamaat, asr_begins, asr_jamaat, maghrib_jamaat, isha_begins, isha_jamaat = results[0]
cursor.close()
print fajr_begins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert it using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). `timedelta` will be use for adding minutes.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> a = "05:27:00"
>>> b = datetime.strptime(a, "%H:%M:%S")
>>> print b
1900-01-01 05:27:00
>>> c = timedelta(minutes=15)
>>> print c
0:15:00
>>> print b+c
1900-01-01 05:42:00
```

Comment: is there a time instance in python without date

Comment: yes, python has `time` module but u cant do direct operation like `add` minutes, hours, days etc.... timedelta cant add timetuple.

Comment: thanks, so i guess i need to convert back to time once i add 15mins

Comment: f=c.strftime('%H:%M:%S')